# JpaSystemException: Could not set value of type

Tags: hibernate, jparepository

I am writing a simple REST API.
So far I have a User and a Circuit Entities. Based on the Hibernate annotations I created a db schema.

```
package com.hydrogarden.server.circuit;

import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
@Transactional
public class CircuitService {
    @Autowired
    private CircuitRepository circuitRepository;
    public List<Circuit> findAll(){
        return circuitRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Circuit findById(int id) {
        return circuitRepository.findById(id).get();
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User extends AbstractEntity {

    private String userName;
    private String hashPassword;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getHashPassword() {
        return hashPassword;
    }

    public void setHashPassword(String hashPassword) {
        this.hashPassword = hashPassword;
    }


    public User() {

    }
    public User(String userName, String hashPassword) {
        super();
        this.userName = userName;
        this.hashPassword = hashPassword;
    }
}
```

```
package com.hydrogarden.server.circuit;

import com.hydrogarden.server.AbstractEntity;
import com.hydrogarden.server.user.User;
import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="circuit")
public class Circuit extends AbstractEntity {

    private String code;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }


}
```

```
package com.hydrogarden.server;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    public AbstractEntity() {

    }

    public AbstractEntity(Long id, Long version) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.version = version;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Long version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
}
```

Now while calling findAll and findById method following error happens :(

```
2022-12-29T01:01:31.512+01:00 ERROR 6672 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not set value of type [com.hydrogarden.server.circuit.Circuit] : `com.hydrogarden.server.circuit.Circuit.user` (setter)] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.hydrogarden.server.user.User field com.hydrogarden.server.circuit.Circuit.user to com.hydrogarden.server.circuit.Circuit
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.FieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(FieldAccessorImpl.java:228) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.FieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(FieldAccessorImpl.java:232) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(MethodHandleObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:115) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:820) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterFieldImpl.set(SetterFieldImpl.java:53) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5140) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.initializeEntity(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:728) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.initializeInstance(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:671) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.coordinateInitializers(StandardRowReader.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.readRow(StandardRowReader.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:33) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:166) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdLoadPlan.load(SingleIdLoadPlan.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdLoadPlan.load(SingleIdLoadPlan.java:110) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.load(SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLoad(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4401) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4391) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:597) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:570) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:363) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1244) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1232) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.access.IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.java:195) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.access.IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.lambda$load$1(IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.java:161) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.access.IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.perform(IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.access.IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.java:161) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:2336) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:2303) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:360) ~[spring-orm-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy105.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:307) ~[spring-orm-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy105.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findById(SimpleJpaRepository.java:313) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:288) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:163) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy113.findById(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.hydrogarden.server.circuit.CircuitService.findById(CircuitService.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at com.hydrogarden.server.circuit.CircuitService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.findById(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.hydrogarden.server.circuit.CircuitController.findById(CircuitController.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1010) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:902) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:705) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]
```

The db schema:

```
create table abstract_entity_seq (next_val bigint) engine=InnoDB;
insert into abstract_entity_seq values ( 1 );
create table circuit (id bigint not null, version bigint, code varchar(255), name varchar(255), user_id bigint, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB;
create table circuit_schedule (id bigint not null, version bigint, enabled bit not null, end_date datetime(6), frequency_days integer not null, start_date datetime(6), watering_time integer not null, circuit_id bigint, user_id bigint, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB;
create table generated_task (id bigint not null, version bigint, datetime datetime(6), done bit not null, mode varchar(255), circuit_id bigint, user_id bigint, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB;
create table user (id bigint not null, version bigint, hash_password varchar(255), user_name varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB;
alter table circuit add constraint FKnh13qt8jj3hko6xfepfsl1yxy foreign key (user_id) references user (id);
alter table circuit_schedule add constraint FK34417y9ycakv6tauwtnljxlgn foreign key (circuit_id) references circuit (id);
alter table circuit_schedule add constraint FKwekisq529eqgfjcgpohwrkga foreign key (user_id) references user (id);
alter table generated_task add constraint FKby4l4rt6licxp3ohq81yraru3 foreign key (circuit_id) references circuit (id);
alter table generated_task add constraint FKn53xcwvd2dyerbjd00gm9kot5 foreign key (user_id) references user (id);
```

I have checked the @ManyToOne relation and this is what I expect to have only one directional relation.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share my experience with this issue, eventhough its not diretly tied to this particular case but i hope it could help someone.

This error means that hibernate is probably dealing with typing and casting problems as this states : https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/PropertyAccessException.html

> A problem occurred accessing a property of an instance of a persistent class by reflection, or via CGLIB. There are a number of possible underlying causes, including :
>
> - failure of a security check
> - an exception occurring inside the getter or setter method
> - a nullable database column was mapped to a primitive-type property
> - the Hibernate type was not castable to the property type (or    vice-versa)

In my particular case i was making use of column property converter :

```
@Convert(converter = StringListConverter.class)
    private ArrayList<String> notificationEmails;
```

while the implementation of the converter class had a List :

```
@Converter
public class StringListConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<String>, String> {
    private static final String SPLIT_CHAR = ",";

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<String> stringList) {
        return stringList != null ? String.join(SPLIT_CHAR, stringList) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> convertToEntityAttribute(String string) {
        return string != null ? Arrays.asList(string.split(SPLIT_CHAR)) : emptyList();
    }
}
```

The solution was to replace List interface by the implementation ArrayList to solve it :

```
@Converter
public class StringListConverter implements AttributeConverter<ArrayList<String>, String> {
    private static final String SPLIT_CHAR = ",";

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(ArrayList<String> stringList) {
        return stringList != null ? String.join(SPLIT_CHAR, stringList) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<String> convertToEntityAttribute(String string) {
        return string != null ? new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(string.split(SPLIT_CHAR))) : new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you probably want `AbstractEntity` to be a `@MappedSuperclass`, not an `@Entity`.

Though, I'm not clear on how *exactly* that explains the error you have.

I tried you code on MySQL and H6.2, and it seemed to work perfectly, so there's something you're not telling us.